# Intellij Idea Regex - Beginning of Line Does Not Seem To WOrk

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to change a character at the beginning of a line with Idea.  I am using the Search/Replace, and Regex is selected.

The $ character works for the end of a line, but not the caret ( ^ ) for beginning.

Am I misinterpreting how to do this?

Thanks.

[image: Edit Screen]

I am able to do this, and it accomplishes the task of inserted a double-quote at the beginning of each line..  I just got used to doing it the first way in other editors.

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me - just tried it on a .java file.  Regex search matched "^public", but not "^interface".  I think you're misinterpreting.

Answer (score 1):

You could try replacing \n with \n"